# Open source Android currency converter

Tags: android, open-source, offline, finance, currency-converter

I want to convert money values from a currency to another, for instance EUR to USD.

Requirements:

- Run on Android
- Open source (imperative)
- Usable offline (exchange rates get updated from time to time, not too strict on that)

Bonus for a easy input of numbers without having to firing up the default software keyboard (which contains all letters whereas I only need numeral and decimal point).

Comment: Note you can enter `50 EUR to USD` in browser and you'll get the answer from Google, works in Android too. Of course it's neither open source nor usable offline.

Comment: I'm curious, could you explain why being open source is important?  I would think that a quick comparison against another app/website would quickly show that it worked and I can't think of any security/privacy concerns unless it is asking for too many permissions.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I don't trust code I did not compile myself. A currency converter will need to update its data from time to time, which means Internet permission, which means the app can report on me (and probably will, as most non-open source apps include statistics gathering clients like libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar)

Answer (score 3):

[Android Currency Converter](https://code.google.com/p/android-currency-converter) seems to be what I was looking for:

[image: Android Currency Converter]

A few drawbacks:

- Not that many currencies
- Maybe a better UI could be designed, even though I have no specific improvement ideas